# QGIS expression to label the highest value that is nearest or within a polygon

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a points geometry layer 'POINTS' with the field "ALTITUDE". And I have a polygon geometry layer 'POLYGONS' with the field "TERRITORY".

[image]

I would need a labeling expression to label the points layer but only the highest value within or nearest to the polygons layer. Like this handmade screenshot capture:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this can be done with the following expression for the label:

```
if ("ALTITUDE"=maximum(expression:="ALTITUDE", 
group_by:=overlay_intersects('POLYGONS',$geometry)),"ALTITUDE",'')
```

Comment: I make a correction to your expression:

`if ("ALTITUDE"=maximum(expression:="ALTITUDE", 
group_by:=overlay_intersects('POLYGONS', "TERRITORY")), "ALTITUDE",'')`

I replace `$geometry` with `"TERRITORY"`.